# Sweetalert does not work but when i test with alert it does

Tags: javascript, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I recently started using Sweetalert but now I don't understand why it doesn't work.

I made a function that retrieves the value of a button that I tested with alert (and it works) but as soon as I put it with sweetalert, the button is validated directly without the sweetalert being displayed.

```js
function dosomething(val) {
  if (val === "Warning") {
    swal({
      html: 'Warning !!!',
      icon: 'warning',
      confirmButtonColor: '#0A717D',
      confirmButtonText: 'Ok',
    });
  }
};
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="src/js/jquery-ui.min.css">
<button type="submit" name="besoin" onclick="dosomething(this.value)" value="Warning">Do something</button>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. It gives errors in the console. You are missing a TITLE

Comment: Voting to close as _Not reproducible or was caused by a typo or some simple issue.
While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **title** attribute was missing from your sweet alert function.

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="src/js/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script>
function dosomething(val)
{
    if (val === "Warning") 
    {
        swal({
            title: 'Warning !!!',
            html: 'Warning !!!',
            icon: 'warning',
            confirmButtonColor: '#0A717D',
            confirmButtonText: 'Ok',
        });
    }
};
</script>
<button type="submit" name="besoin" onclick="dosomething(this.value)" value="Warning">Warning</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    openAreYouSureDialogDocument(training): void {
     if('warning'){
        Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Warning !!!',
                    text: 'Warning !!!',
                    icon: 'warning',
                    confirmButtonColor: '#0A717D',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Ok',
        }).then((result) => {
          if (result.value) {
           //  if all good 
          }
        }).catch(err => console.log(err))
}
      }
```